# Why does my DSL router show wireless activity when all my devices are turned off?

Tags: wireless-router

My DSL router constantly shows wireless activity even while all my devices are powered off. From [page 5 of the instruction manual](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/1106303/Pace-5268ac.html?page=5):

> **Wireless:** *Flickering green. There is inbound or outbound activity. The flickering of the light is synchronized to data traffic.*

Data traffic from ATT is not wireless.

The modem passively broadcasting that it is available causes the flickering? But the flickering is very random.

What else might be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A monitor mode packet trace would likely be required to know for sure.

It could be a mixture of beacons (10 per second), probe responses to probe requests (scans) from other devices nearby (possibly a neighbor's devices), and multicast service advertisements, such as IPv6 router advertisements, mDNS, and UPnP.

Comment: I used the "Wireless Diagnostics" of MacOS. It is a mixture like you said.

Answer (score 0):

Outbound activity can be linked to the beacon activity of your wireless interface. 
Even if your DSL router does not have any wireless clients connected it beams your **SSID** (network name), and as the LED green light is connected to the DSL router hardware it shows some activity.